# Nested Github Projects With Nested Commit / Whole Commit to single repo

Tags: github, phpstorm

I am working on a project which has 2 github repo required to develop this project. and then project structure looks like this

```
- project-folder -- Connected To Github
   --- inc
   --- git-repo1 -- Connected To Github
     --- inc
        --- git-repo2 -- Connected To Github
```

as of now i am able to commit each and every repo to their github repo. but i am not able to commit a project folder with all its sub github .

Eg

if i go the project url
i can see only the inc folder
not the git-repo1 folder

and if i go the git-repo1 url in can see only inc not the git-repo2
is there anyway to get this done ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039633/how-do-i-mount-one-github-repository-as-a-subfolder-of-another-repository

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks but i dont want to use it as a submodule.

Comment: Then what do you want? You want to have everything in one repository? Why you're using 3 repositories then?

Comment: I need like project repo should have both git-repo1 and git-repo2 source in it.

Comment: The facilities git provides to do what you want are submodules and subtrees. *shrug*